# How can I export Aperture projects to folders that are named according to library project names?

Tags: aperture

I want to upload an Aperture library to a FTP/SFTP server for use with Zenphoto. Since Aperture doesn't have it built in, and since uberupload doesn't appear to exist any longer, I figured it would be fairly straightforward -- install sshfs and Fuse4X, export the Aperture library to a folder, and then drag the folder into the SSH mount.

The problem is, it appears that Aperture doesn't have a built-in function to export a library to a folder (i.e. if the library contains the projects "Hiking" "Biking" and "Fishing", there should be three folders created with the respective names and all the photos should be dumped in each). But apparently, you can only export a project to a .aplibrary file. Granted, this is really just a folder, and you can find the folders inside, but I'd have to manually rename every folder -- not optimal, since there are a ton of projects.

Short of writing an AppleScript (which I'm somewhat resigned to doing), is there any solution? Literally all I need to do is to export the library to a folder structure.

Comment: Andrew - please don't mix the answer with the question. It's OK (even encouraged) to answer and accept your own answer as long as you do it jeopardy style - keep the question simple and put the answer / explanation in the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution: just go into the Photos sidebar item and export from there. All the projects will be put in their appropriate folders.

Comment: Can you explain or share snapshot? I don't see how is would do it. @andrew min